# Ionic Webview not syncing cookies on first launch IOS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webview, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

Please help!! I’m using Ionic 5 with Angular and Cordova. My app works perfect when testing on browsers and Android devices but when it’s first installed on my device (iphone) through Xcode the cookies are not received or sent properly. My app uses cookie based authentication so when I get my login response it will have a cookie that should be sent with all subsequent requests. However, on the first launch after install I cannot login at all. When I exit and relaunch my app it works perfectly. I believe this is due to the webview not syncing cookies correctly. I have tried all the solutions in this post: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/247 but the plugins are so outdated I can’t get it to work properly.

I have been looking for a solution for weeks and am completely stuck and exhausted at this point. I’m new to Ionic and development in general so any help would be greatly appreciated! I will provide whatever code or screenshots is helpful, just let me know what I should share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this since it's been 24 days since you asked, but:

I was having a similar issue. I'm using the cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookie-sync plugin
and even though the cookie was set, the page was loading as it wasn't. All I had to do was
update $('body').append(_return); to $('body').html(_return); and the content showed up
using the cookie.

This is my code:

```js
function loadApp() {
  $.ajax({
    // this url sets the cookie when called
    url: "example.com",
    success: function (_return) {
      if (_return) {
        // the _return value uses the cookie to display custom data
        // I previously used the append() method here
        $("body").html(_return);
      }
    },
  });
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  wkWebView.injectCookie(
    "www.example.com/index",
    function () {
      // success callback
      loadApp();
    },
    function () {
      // error callback
      //alert('error');
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I actually posted a reply on the plugin I used to get it working here: https://github.com/lucky3491/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie/issues/1